# Azure OCR RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync Invalid Image

Tags: xamarin, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the Azure OCR API in Xamarin Forms. Here is the important bits of code. I'm using the ComputerVisionClient .net client

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

  if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
  {
    return;
  }

  var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
  {
    SaveToAlbum = false
  });

  Img = new Image
  {
    Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
      var stream = file.GetStream();
      return stream;
    }),
  };

  using (var photoStream = file.GetStream())
  {
    var text = await _client.RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync(true, photoStream);
  }
```

The Img is bound to an image on the view and it shows up when I take a picture so there is definetly an image. However RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync returns back "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Invalid Image'" and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Edit. Added _client code

```
public static ComputerVisionClient Authenticate(string endpoint, string key)
{
    ComputerVisionClient client =
        new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(key))
        { Endpoint = endpoint };
    return client;
}
```

Called from my constructor and set as a global var

```
_client = Authenticate(endpoint, subscriptionKey);
```

Thanks

Comment: I test the code, the image exists. I do not have _client, please provide more details about this. It would be better to provide a simple sample which could reproduce the error.

Comment: @WendyZang the _client comes from this quickstart - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/csharp-sdk#authenticate-the-client added code to question. The image does exist it's just the RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync that doesn't like it but I'm not sure why

Comment: I create the endpoint and key to test, do not get the invalid image  error. Please check the requirements: 1. Supported image formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP. 2. Image file size must be less than 4MB. For more information, you could refer to the link below.https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5cd27ec07268f6c679a3e641/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499f20d